# Too many SOQL queries in batch class

Tags: apex, batch

When we are running the below batch getting:

> Too many SOQL queries: 201 Error.

What are some steps I can take to avoid this error?

Batch: Will post the code.Sorry for the deletion

Thanks

Comment: You should refactor this class. It's a terrible wall of code and will continue to cause you problems until you break it out into some more discrete functionality.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry to say I didn't read the whole code (too long), but with a quick glance I found this query inside a `for(Opportunity opp : newOppListfromOpp)` loop:

```
assetsList = [Select id,ParentId,Service_Contract__c,type__c,GlobalCare_Level__c,Asset_Value__c,smart_part_number__c from Asset where AccountId in :accList and GlobalCare_Level__c!='None' and GlobalCare_Level__c!='' and Type_of_Key__c != 'Demo' and Status = 'Active'];
```

**You should never have SOQL queries inside loops.** Fix that one and look for other occurrences, that is very much likely to be the cause of your Exception. The alternative is to make that query outside of a loop only once, and you can make a `Map<Id, SObject>` to map the queried objects and be able access them inside the loop later, instead of making the query there.